# passing more than one items variable into a Bootstrap modal with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out how to pass more than one variable into a bootstrap modal. I know how to pass one variable but I can not figure out how to send two variable. Can I add two variable to the same link below.

I would like to add one more Item Like this

```
<a data-id="<?=$sid?>" class="open-AddsigningId btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="#PaySigning">Pay Signing</a>
```

This is the jquery script

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-AddsigningId", function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var _self = $(this);

    var mysignId = _self.data('id');
    $("#signId").val(mysignId);

    $(_self.attr('href')).modal('show');
});
```

This is the modal I am passing the items to

```
<!--Pay Signing-->

<div class="modal fade" id="PaySigning" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Pay Signing</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="row well">
      <form action="formpross.php" id="closeform" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">

        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
        <label  for="totalowed" class="control-label">Total Owed:</label>  
        <input name="totalowed" type="text"id="totalowed" class="form-control input-sm"/> 
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">    
        <label  for="paiddate" class="control-label">Paid Date:</label>   
        <input name="paiddate" type="text"id="datepicker1" class="form-control input-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Date the signing company paid the invoice" value="<?php echo $paiddate;?>"> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
        <label  for="totalpaid" class="control-label">Total Paid:</label>  
        <input name="totalpaid" type="text"id="totalpaid" class="form-control input-sm"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">         
        <label  for="checkn" class="control-label">Check Number:</label>  
        <input name="checkn" type="text"id="checkn" class="form-control input-sm"data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Check Number of the check from the signing company" value="<?php echo $checkn;?>"> 
        </div>
      </div>


       <div class="modal-footer">
        <input name="id" id="signId" type="hidden" value=""/> 
        <input name="pid" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $pid;?>"/>
        <input name="processtp" type="hidden" value="paysigning"/>
        <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-xs center">Pay Signing</button>
      </div>
      </form>
      </div>
      </div>

    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: add 1 more `data-*` attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use any number of `data-*` attributes

```
<a data-id="<?=$sid?>" data-something="<?=$somevalue?>" class="open-AddsigningId btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="#PaySigning">Pay Signing</a>
```

then

```
var something= _self.data('something');
$("#something").val(something);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Did not know I could do this